# Detect touch for android....for unity 3d

Tags: android, unity, touch

i am trying to detect the touch on android and is it possible to have a same function with touch which can work same as OnMouseUp() function

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, Google that stuff:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html

There is a complete manual on unity. Took me just one google search.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to develop the touch functionality you have to write input.getmousebuttondown,input.getmousebuttonup,input.getmousebutton will work.One more way also there touch pahse began,thouchphase.end.
 OnMouseUp() and OnMouseDown() will work only for windows,mac.It won't support for mobiles(ios and android).

check this links